# Python code for deleting a list is not working

Tags: python, list

The following function should delete a element in an list if it has an overlap with a first list.
However it only works with the first example(a and b1). With others it does not even send an error message and I have no idea where there problem lies. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```py
def funct(firstone, secondone):
    counter = 0
    while secondone != [] and counter < len(firstone):
        if firstone[counter] in secondone:
            del(secondone[secondone.index(firstone[counter])])
            counter += 1
        return secondone


a = [0, 1, 2]
b1 = [1, 2, 0]
b2 = [-1, 1, 1]
b3 = [0, 0, 2]
print(funct(a, b1))
print(funct(a, b2))
print(funct(b3, a))
```

Comment: In almost any other language users of the site could help you with formatting the code in the question, but in the case of Python indentation is part of the structure. Please revise that everything appears at the indentation level where you have it in the real code. A way of doing that is copy-pasting the real code, selecting it, and using the `{}` button (it adds 4 spaces in front of the selected lines, creating a code-formatted block)

Comment: @MartinDK In your second input (a and b2), the `While` condition is never `False`. After deleted second element in `b2` list, the `counter` will never increase again and `b2` still remains two elements `[-1, 1]`, this goes into an infinite loop.

Solution: Move counter += 1 to outside `if` condition, move `return` statement to outside `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think last line in your code "return" must be in the same level with "while" loop like that

```
def funct(firstone, secondone ):
    counter = 0
    while secondone != [] and counter < len(firstone):
        if firstone [counter] in secondone :
            del(secondone[ secondone .index(firstone[counter ])])
            counter += 1
    return secondone
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue the for loop when the condition is `False` otherwise you will always return on the first iteration

```
          while secondone != [] and counter < len(firstone):
              if firstone[counter] in secondone :
                  del(secondone[secondone.index(firstone[counter])])
                  counter += 1
              else:
                  continue
          return secondone
```